# MariaDB - database folder changed?

Tags: macos, mysql, homebrew, mariadb

I have MariaDB installed via Homebrew on MacOS.

I have local databases in `/usr/local/var/mysql` but a day or two ago, my local MariaDB now points to `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql` and does not find any of my existing databases.

I did not find any configuration file, so I'm not sure why this change occurred.

How can I update the directory for databases to be back to the `/usr/local/var/mysql` version or move/update all databases to be in the new default folder location?